# How to switch numbers and characters location in a string in python?

Tags: python, string

I have file names like this:
13_CL
13_CR
13_TL
13_TR
...
and I assigned them to a variable. I need to switch numbers and alphabetical characters in the filenames.
the expected result is:
CL_13
CR_13
TL_13
TR_13
...

Comment: For each name, `switched_name = '_'.join(reversed(name.split('_')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a regex approach here:

```py
filenames = ['13_CL', '13_CR', '13_TL', '13_TR']
output = [re.sub(r'(.*)_(.*)', r'\2_\1', x) for x in filenames]
print(output)  # ['CL_13', 'CR_13', 'TL_13', 'TR_13']
```

Comment: Also good other option ;-) for `OP`, `re` is a module to import.

Answer (score 2):

You might split the value on `_` then reverse the array and join back with a `_`

```
s="13_CL"
print('_'.join(s.split('_')[::-1]))
```

Output

```
CL_13
```

---

A regex solution to switch numbers and alphabetical characters could be to capture 1+ digits in group 1 and 1+ chars A-Z in group 2 and in the replacement use the groups in the reversed order.

```
import re

s="13_CL"
print(re.sub(r"(\d+)_([A-Z]+)", r"\2_\1", s))
```

Output

```
CL_13
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lots of possibilities here.

One is :

```py
filename_list = ['13_CL', '13_CR', '13_TL', '13_TR']
new_filename_list = ['_'.join(reversed(filename.split('_'))) for filename in filename_list]
```

`split` split the string into a list on delimiter

`reversed` is used to reverse the list order. It produces an iterator which is consumed directly by `join` without the need to really create a full list object.

`join` to create a new string from a iterable using a delimiter

Comment: @shinra_tensei also proposes to use `revesed` function instead of `[::-1]` construction which I think is better (because it creates a iterator)

Comment: first of you could have put that info in your post (use [edit])

Comment: @CyrillePontvieux Why would an iterator be better?

Comment: I edited my post and also added an explanation why an iterator is a better idea in this case

Comment: So you're not familiar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/12671057) or is it not true anymore?

Comment: It’s still true and this is why creating a list for join is not as good as creating an iterator or generator for it.

Comment: Huh? It says *list* is better.

Comment: No it isn’t, it says creating a list-comprehension is worse than creating a list directly. But this is worse than just creating a iterator.

Comment: That's not what it says and you're not making any sense.

Comment: Ok my bad, yes for the CPython implementation of `str.join` it’s a bit faster to have a list because the implementation seems to need to read the data twice. Nevertheless it’s better to use Iterators in general cases, even if in that special case (using CPython) you don’t get faster run. It’s an implementation detail that is subject to change. So for the OP learning curve, I still think it’s better to user iterators whenever it’s possible. Feel free to contradict me.

Comment: Maybe, but *"consumed directly by join without the need to really create a full list object"* is still misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line version:

```
s = ' '.join(['_'.join(reversed(pair.split('_'))) for pair in s.split(' ')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str1='13_CL 13_CR 13_TL 13_TR'
str2=' '.join('_'.join(reversed(a.split('_'))) for a in str1.split())
print(str2)
```